# How to create instance(or class)method properly(associated models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I want to add instance method(or class), but constatly get unefined method error.

Website has associated with report, which has value. I need to get this value.

**Here how I want to call it in my views:**

```
 <%websites.each do |website|%>
   //and use website.amount here
```

Here is my code from WebsiteController(**I know that this code is for class method**):

```
  def self.amount
      self.performance_report.conversions
  end
```

I can't get how to make it properly, should it be class or instance method and how it should be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add that method in your model, not in your controller. It's an instance method, so it should be `def amount`:

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
  def amount
    self.performance_report.conversions
  end
end
```

With this you can do the following in your view:

```
<% websites.each do |website| %>
  <%= website.amount %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Website.find() returns an instance of Website.

if a Website has one performance_report, and PerformanceRecord has a field conversions,

```
 Website.find(38).performance_report.conversions
```

should work without defining any methods. You should check your Association definitions if this does not work as expected. Defining class methods on the Controller will not have any effect.

Comment: Maybe my question is a little bit wrong. I mean to call method in my view. I will edit question.